# Type narrowing is not working in for loop

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-narrowing

Type narrowing is not working in for loop.

How to fix to work type narrowing correctly in for loop?

Below is a simple example(Please run it on TS playground)

```js
// string or null is unsure until runtime
const htmlElements = [
  { textContent: Math.random() < 0.5 ? "test": null },
  { textContent: Math.random() < 0.5 ? "test": null },
  { textContent: Math.random() < 0.5 ? "test": null },
];


const contents: {
  content: string;
}[] = [];

// type narrowing work
if (typeof htmlElements[0].textContent === "string") {
  contents.push({ content: htmlElements[0].textContent });
}

// type narrowing not work
for (const i in htmlElements) {
  if (htmlElements[i].textContent && typeof htmlElements[i].textContent === "string") {
    contents.push({
      content: htmlElements[i].textContent // <-- Error: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'. textContent: string | null
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is [ms/TS#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530); narrowing doesn't happen when the property's index isn't a single literal type.  You should refactor to copy the property to a variable before checking... or really, just do a `for (const el of htmlElements)` instead of following the [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/2887218) of iterating over the keys of an array.  Both versions can be seen [in the playground](https://tsplay.dev/N55r5N). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Your proposal and GitHub issue is what I was looking for.
for (const el of htmlElements) solved my issue! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `i` in `for (const i in htmlElements) {}` is `string` (you might have expected `number`, but enumerating *keys* of objects, even arrays, will give you strings and not numbers).  And so `htmlElements[i]` is obtained by indexing into an array with an unknown index.  The compiler doesn't check this by checking the *identity* of `i`; it does so by checking the *type* of `i`.  So the obvious truism `htmlElements[i] === htmlElements[i]` is not seen by the compiler; if you had a `j` of the same type as `i`, you wouldn't be able to conclude that `htmlElements[i] === htmlElements[j]`.  And neither can the compiler.  This inability for the compiler to track indexes unless they are of a single [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) is a longstanding issue in TypeScript, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).

Until and unless this is addressed, you'd need to work around it. The standard workaround is to copy the value to its own variable and then do your checks on the variable, so you're only indexing once:

```
for (const i in htmlElements) {
    const el = htmlElements[i];
    if (el.textContent && typeof el.textContent === "string") {
        contents.push({
            content: el.textContent
        });
    }
}
```

Here `el` is copied from `htmlElements[i]`, and after this, all the narrowing works as expected.

---

**However** in this  particular case you should refactor further.  It is considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/2887218) to iterate over the keys of arrays with [a `for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).  Unless you actually need to look at the numeric index, in modern JavaScript, you should probably use [a `for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead, which gives you each element as a variable to start with:

```
for (const el of htmlElements) {
    if (el.textContent && typeof el.textContent === "string") {
        contents.push({
            content: el.textContent
        });
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGcBcCcEsDsDmoD21TwK4BtuluKJvOJtAKZHySx7TE0C25AUAMYomSgAWkj2AKLZyzaoQC8oANotQ80AG9QkcgA9IAYU6rqALlABZAIaQeAOmjH4AExSMAFAEpQAHlAAGcwFZQAflAAIlUoQNADLFxQAF8AGjkFZVUNbWpyfSNTCytbe2c3Tx9-IJDIMIicPDiE+ST1LR10yAMTM0trO0cXdy9fAODyUPCMSpj4gF0AbhYZji5QOd1IcANFGoXGjKg4JGno6XHQKQPplhAVAE8AB0p4Y2hoFAB3BGQntABrFlgAM1AHSDXcgoP58ATCURNcDSDzjczJBppahHCRSQLbV6BFxrBQbJHLcxXTDgHgOZSLJoGMFCERiZYwuEI1JLGJOPYzc6Am4Ye6PF5IeTvaBfH5of5zKD4fDwXj8GmQ8TY9YS7jkPBSakQunQ2BTda-f5q+H1ZlNUAAMnNlxuINARqZm24qLRGKQWKU61xFPEhOJpJxuMD8m9zTt2GNKUdnoU0TZ62iLATLFF6AcKrDqFBcq1UKVuINDntJsdFqtXOBfyLkfxKJdMExeaDeKW4F9JLJ0aDIYMVcRS07rOmuITSaAA)